# reading pptx with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

i am using the python-pptx module to read contents of the file but sadly, i only get the text from the headers of every slide ..pfb the code i am using

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation('Birds eye view - product.pptx')
for slide in prs.slides:
  for shapes in slide.shapes:
    print( shapes.shape_type )
    print( '----------------' )
    if shapes.has_text_frame:
      print( shapes.text )
```

any pointers on how i could get the content inside every slide ? please note that all slides have smart art (within which i have text). The only other option i really have is to open the xml data files and read all the text there BUT even there , the text is read left to right , ignoring any sort of vertical listing of bullet points inside a smart art list / chart etc.

Comment: You probably already know that you can access texts using the `placeholders` property of a slide. I regret that I don't know what is meant by 'smart art'.

Comment: Can you make a powerpoint file available to us all that has all the features you want to contend with?

Comment: Thanks a ton Bill ..please find the pptx here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B90ORDKPqlkZNktDa051TlpZRU0/view?usp=sharing ..also smart art is that feature where u can insert stuff like lists, flow charts etc and put text in them

Answer (score 0):

`python-pptx` does not support SmartArt I'm afraid (and is unlikely ever to), so you're on your own for any content that appears in those objects.

Comment: primarily, thanks for putting out an awesome package! i have kinda figured out how to read the info i need and will be posting the code here shortly.